# Extra copy of sidebar appears in footer

Tags: sidebar

I have an extra copy of the sidebar content appearing after the last post and before the footer in the output HTML. So I have one on the side in the correct position, and one at the end of the page. Any idea on how to get rid of the second one?

functions.php

```
/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#registering-a-sidebar
 */
function isometricland_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'isometricland' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'isometricland' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'isometricland_widgets_init' );
```

footer.php

```
<?php
    global $path_root, $page_title, $path_img, $path_ssi, $path_css, $path_jav;
    include_once($path_ssi . 'plugin-paypal.php');
    include_once($path_ssi . 'plugin-sitesearch.php');
    include_once($path_ssi . 'plugin-socialicons.php');
    include_once($path_ssi . 'plugin-norml.php');
?>
                </main>
                <!-- END PAGE CONTENTS -->
                <!-- START FOOTERS -->
                <div id="footframe">
                    <footer>
                        <div><small><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s.', 'isometricland' ), 'WordPress' ); ?> <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by Michael Horvath based on %2$s GPLv2 or later.', 'isometricland' ), 'isometricland', '<a href="http://underscores.me/" rel="designer">Underscores.me</a>' ); ?></small></div>
                        <div><small>&gt;&gt;&gt;<a href="https://isometricland.net/pages/sitemap.php">sitemap</a>&lt;&lt;&lt;</small></div>
                    </footer>
<?php wp_footer(); //Crucial footer hook! ?>
                </div>              
                <!-- END FOOTERS -->
            </div>
            <!-- END MIDDLE PANE -->
            <!-- START SIDEBAR -->
            <div id="leftframe">
                <div id="sidebarframetop">
                    <div id="sidebar_widget">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebarframebot">
                    <div id="file_paypal">
<?php //echo writePaypalDonate(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="file_search">
<?php //echo writeSiteSearchForm(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="file_social">
<?php echo writeSocialIcons(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="file_norml">
<?php //echo writeNormlLogo(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<?php
    global $path_root, $page_title, $path_img, $path_ssi, $path_css, $path_jav;
    include_once($path_ssi . 'plugin-analyticstracking.php');
    include_once($path_ssi . 'plugin-verytopbar.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
<?php echo writeAnalyticsTracking(); ?>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
        <link rel="alternate" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path_css; ?>style-main.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path_css; ?>style-dropdown.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo $path_root; ?>favicon.png"/>
        <script src="<?php echo $path_jav; ?>dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo $path_jav; ?>cubesnake.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <div id="seed_pane"><img id="seed_image" src="https://isometricland.net/svg/seed_of_life_monochrome.svg"/></div>
        <div id="snake_pane"></div>
        <div id="outerframe">

            <!-- START MIDDLE PANE -->
            <div id="middleframe">
                <!-- START FAUX WP ADMIN BAR -->
                <div id="verytopbar">
                    <nav role="navigation">
<?php echo writeVeryTopBar(); ?>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!-- END FAUX WP ADMIN BAR -->
                <!-- START PAGE CONTENTS -->
                <main>
```

sidebar.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Isometricland
 */

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $path_root = "../../../../";
    $path_img = "../../../../images/";
    $path_css = "../../../../css/";
    $path_jav = "../../../../java/";
    $path_ssi = "../ssi/";
    $page_title = "Blog";
    include_once($path_ssi . 'directory.php');
    include_once($path_ssi . 'getpageinfo.php');
?>
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package Isometricland
 */

get_header();
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <?php
            endif;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

single.php

```
<?php
    $path_root = "../../../../";
    $path_img = "../../../../images/";
    $path_css = "../../../../css/";
    $path_jav = "../../../../java/";
    $path_ssi = "../ssi/";
    $page_title = "Blog";
    include_once($path_ssi . 'directory.php');
    include_once($path_ssi . 'getpageinfo.php');
?>
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package Isometricland
 */

get_header();
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            the_post_navigation();

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Screenshot of two copies of sidebar.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this index.php? What is the code of that template?

Comment: Yes, it is index.php, but it occurs on individual posts and pages too. Which template/file do you want the code of? I'm kind of a WP newbie.

Comment: This sidebar below the post located in your single.php file. - `get_sidebar()` and page.php file also has a call of `get_sidebar()`, so it's not in your footer.php

Comment: @posfan12 index.php and sidebar.php, if you have them.

Comment: Thanks! I added sidebar.php, index.php and single.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you look at all the templates included in your question, the reason becomes obvious: You're outputting the sidebar twice.

In index.php you use `get_sidebar()`, which loads `sidebar.php`. In that template you're outputting the widgets:

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

You're also using `get_footer()`, which loads `footer.php`. In that template you're *also* outputting the widgets:

```
                    <div id="sidebar_widget">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Aha! The underscores theme was initially set up with `get_sidebar()` being called inside both `header.php` and `index.php`, and it did not cause issues in that particular configuration for whatever reason. No doubt the developers fixed the theme since then and I didn't notice it or update it. Thanks for figuring it out!

Comment: Or maybe I am misremembering. It was 5+ years ago.